# Receiving wrong data in _beginthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I want to pass int variable to thread.

My thread code:

```
void record_WAVthread(void* data)
{
    int channelId = *(int*)data;
    cout<< "\n THREAD CREATED " << channelId;

    (...)

    _endthread();
}
```

My thread creation code:

```
extern HANDLE thread_audio_recording[MAX_INPUTS];
extern void record_WAVthread(void* data);

(...)  

case 's':
    if (!flag_recordingAudio) 
    {   
        //start recording
        audioRecManager.isRecording = flag_recordingAudio = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
        {
            thread_audio_recording[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(record_WAVthread, 0, &i);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Output:

```
 THREAD CREATED 0
 THREAD CREATED 5
 THREAD CREATED 5
 THREAD CREATED 9
 THREAD CREATED 14
 THREAD CREATED 15
 THREAD CREATED 12
 THREAD CREATED 11
 THREAD CREATED 9
 THREAD CREATED 12
 THREAD CREATED 8
 THREAD CREATED 7
 THREAD CREATED 4
 THREAD CREATED 2
 THREAD CREATED 3
 THREAD CREATED 6
```

What am I doing wrong? I should get 1-16.

Comment: i goes from 0 to 15.  Why should you get 1-16?  also, why pass a pointer to i into beginthread?  why not pass i directly?

Comment: True 0-15 my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the address of stack variable to a thread function as argument, which is a common mistake in Windows multithreading programming.

`&i` point to a temporary stack variable which could not keep its value outside its scope. It could be any value after the case. You need to use heap variables as the thread function's argument.

But for your code, here is a simple solution in particular.

```
case 's':
    if (!flag_recordingAudio) 
    {   
        //start recording
        audioRecManager.isRecording = flag_recordingAudio = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
        {
            thread_audio_recording[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(record_WAVthread, 0, (void*)i);
        }
    }
    break;

void record_WAVthread(void* data)
{
    int channelId = (int)data;
    cout<< "\n THREAD CREATED " << channelId;

    (...)

    _endthread();
}
```

Comment: I get the same error after I made those changes. Strange

Comment: @F1sher: There should no error in the value. But the order of the numbers could changed,  because the execution order of the threads 0~15 is uncertain.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice. Thanks for posting working edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer to 'i', of which the value keeps changing. When it starts the first thread, 'i' may already have (and, judging from your output, it has by the second thread creation) changed and your thread will not produce the output you expect.

If you want to do this right, create an int array of size 16, fill it with 0, 1, 2,.. and pass a pointer to the array element indexed by 'i' (i.e. &arr[i])

Another solution is to fool the compiler and not pass a pointer, but pass 'i' itself, casted to a void pointer. Of course, in the thread you don't dereference it then, but simply cast it back to int.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mutex in thread callback function.

```
std::mutex g_mutex;
void record_WAVthread(void* data)
{
    g_mutex.lock();
    int channelId = *(int*)data;
    cout<< "\n THREAD CREATED " << channelId;
    g_mutex.unlock();
    (...)

    _endthread();
}
```